# Django Adding a ManyToManyField to ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Sorry that this is like the thousandth question for this issue but I still can't see a light at the end of the tunnel.

Lets say I have two models:

```
class Video(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(u"Titel",max_length=200)
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title',unique=True)
date = models.DateField("Datum")
description = models.TextField(u"Beschreibung")
user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)

class Channel(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(u"Name",max_length=30)
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name',unique=True)
videos = models.ManyToManyField('videoportal.Video',related_name="contained_videos",blank=True,null=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

As you see I want to have a channel with video(s) in it. So if I ad a video using a ModelForm like this

```
class VideoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
```

the form I get will not contain a input field to select a channel (of course not). So how can I do this? How can I have a input field in my form to select one channel with a drop down?

Thanks,
Philip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a video only belongs in one channel just give your `Video` model a `ForeignKey` to your `Channel` model. If it should belong to more than one channel I'd use a `ManyToManyField` in the `Video` model, as already suggested.

I think this would fit the idea of uploading videos and adding it to a channel far better than doing it the other way around.

Comment: Your are right, I got it all wrong because I was thinking much to complicated. Thank you (and all the others) for your help, I really appreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom form instead of Django ModelForm.

probably something like this,

```
class VideoForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    description = forms.TextField()
    channel = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Channel.objects.all(), empty_label=None)
```

do your validation in a view. Use `Model save()` method to save information contained in your POSTed form.

Comment: OK do you have any code or example? Do I need to write my own save() methods and so on?

Comment: no need to write your own save method. Just get the information using the form, then use mModel save() (eg `new_vid = Video(title=form.cleaned_data['title']); new_vid.save(); new_vid.channel_set.add(your_selected_channel))`

Comment: Also you can change structure of your models by adding `ManyToManyField` to Video Model instead of Channel Model

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the ManyToMany field in the `Video` model and omit it from the `Channel` model:

```
class Video(model.Model):
    ...
    channels = model.ManyToManyField('videoportal.Channel', related_name='videos')
    ...
```

If you want a simple dropdown to select a single channel, why is it a many-to-many realationship between videos and channels?